# Сохранить переменные скрипта в Cookie перед закрытием страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток.
Скрипт работая фиксирует время которое пользователь проводит просматривая закладки табов.
Но при закрытии закладки или браузера, время проведенное за просмотром табы не сохраняется =( пробовал разные body.onunload, window.onclose и т.п.
Как можно реализовать выполнение моей функции (сохранения в куках переменных) при закрытии вкладки или браузера? (document.cookie закрывается по ходу раньше чем window)
Если есть вариант с использованием JQury то тоже подойдет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/s8ss8/2/

Что конкретно не работает ?

Comment: Я просто делал так же но вставлял alert. так он показывался не в тему, или не показывался при закрытии вкладки и браузера.

Comment: когда выгружается страница запускается эта функция.